# ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 11) are incompatible

Tags: python

I am training a CoVID Xrays Dataset. While training the model getting error as
`ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 11) are incompatible`

```
opt = Adam(lr=0.00001)
model_transfer_full.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model_transfer_full.fit(train_x, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10, validation_data=(validate_x, y_val), 
                                  callbacks=[checkpointer],verbose=1, shuffle=True)
```

Getting error on callbacks.

Can someone tell where it is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing this

```
model_transfer_full.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

with the following code might help you in solving the issue.

```
model_transfer_full.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Kindly add additional information like the model, checkpoints in the question for better assistance. Thank you!